# How to replace a selected text in livecode?

Tags: livecode

I need to replace a selected string which is separated by commas (eg: sam,san) to "sam" only in the selected occurance.

```
on mouseUp
   put the selectedText of field "MytextField" into Ftext
   set the itemDel to comma
   put item 1 of Ftext into xsearch
   put item 2 of Ftext into xreplace
   replace the selectedText with xsearch  in field "MytextField"
end mouseUp
```

But it is not working.

Comment: I have tried it and it works. Why doesn't it work for you? Do you get an unexpected result? Which result do you expect instead? Do you get any errors? Post the exact text of the errors together with your questions.

Comment: I need only in the selected occurance (current line). I don't need  to replace this globally.

Comment: I understand the problem now and I have posted an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The following script puts the required string into the selection without replacing any other occurrences of the string:

```
on mouseUp
   put the selectedText of field "MytextField" into Ftext
   set the itemDel to comma
   put item 2 of fText into the selection
end mouseUp
```